# Make Existing Job Rundeck to .tfstate

Tags: terraform, rundeck

we know there is a tool called **terraformer** -> https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/terraformer . It can make existing architecture (example GCE) to file .tfstate . But I wondering, there is a terraform provider rundeck -> https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/rundeck/index.html , and my question is how we change existing job in rundeck into file .tfstate?

Because I want to make all job in my rundeck is manage from terraform.

Comment: There is an [outstanding pull request](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-rundeck/pull/44) that should add the ability to run `terraform import` with a Rundeck job. Until then it can't be done.